# Parallel programming: create a certain number of processes and related data/work

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, multiprocessing

I need to allocate a workload on different processes, depending on the number of logical cores of the user's PC.
The workload is done by the following code :

```
static void work()
{
    WorkData myData = new WorkData();
    Worker myWorker = new Worker(myData);
    MyWorker.doWork()
}
```

I count the logical cores with this code :

```
int nbProcessors = 1;
foreach (var item in new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select *  from Win32_ComputerSystem").Get())
{
    nbProcessors = Convert.ToInt32(item["NumberOfLogicalProcessors"]);
}
```

Now, I have to do my work() 10000 times, by sharing the work on the logical cores, so in the case of my pc it would mean starting 8 processes with 1250 iterations of work() each.
I also need each process to have its own data, so that I don't get conflicts.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use `Parallell.ForAll()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should review [Parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx) methods and [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) methods.
Both of this classes are counting on current workstation configuration, so you can easily use them for your task.

Example of Parrallel usage:

[Parallel Loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx):

```
int n = 10 000;
Parallel.For(0, n, (i, loopState) =>
{
  // ... 
  if (/* stopping condition is true */)
  {
    loopState.Break();
    return;   
  }
});
```

[Thread Pool task-oriented example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4732ks0.aspx):

```
public void DoWork()
{
    // Queue a task.
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        new System.Threading.WaitCallback(SomeLongTask));
    // Queue another task.
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        new System.Threading.WaitCallback(AnotherLongTask));
}

private void SomeLongTask(Object state)
{
    // Insert code to perform a long task.
}

private void AnotherLongTask(Object state)
{
    // Insert code to perform a long task.
}
```

**Update from comments:**

[Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) (Parralel class) internally uses Threading.Tasks namespace, with some process managing:

> the scheduling of threads on the ThreadPool

Two another links about: [Task Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) and [Data Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx). I think second link can help you with balancing the work for your data.

> When possible, the scheduler redistributes work among multiple threads and processors if the workload becomes unbalanced.

Comment: If I got it right, Parallel.For is multi processing while threadpool is just multithreading in one process isnt it ?

Answer (score 2):

Since C# 4.0 you can use [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), it does the load balancing automatically:

```
Parallel.For(0, 10000, p => work());
```

or

```
ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, 10000).ForAll(p => work());
```

See: [Parallel Programming in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx):

```
   Parallel.For (0,10000, item => {
       WorkData myData = new WorkData();
       Worker myWorker = new Worker(myData);
       MyWorker.doWork()
   });
```

it will automatically split between cores. But if you need, you can set number of threads manually

Answer (score 1):

Ummm, you know you can get the logical processor count by accessing property:

```
Environment.ProcessorCount
```

Which returns 8 on my quad-core HT machine - kind of checks out.

If you have a fixed number of iterations (instead of doing e.g. iterations over a list or something)
then you can go with:

```
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelistm = Environment.ProcessorCount
};


//edited per comment
Parallel.For(0, 10000, parallelOptions, () =>
{
    WorkData myData = new WorkData();
    Worker myWorker = new Worker(myData);
    MyWorker.doWork() 
});
```

If you had to do some partitioning of a list, then partitioner comes into play:

```
var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(yourList);
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};

Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, parallelOptions, (listItem, loopState) =>
{
   //Do something
}
```

Although mind you that AFAIK the `Parallel` loops by default spawn as many threads as there are cores.

Comment: Actually if I do iterationsPerCore = 10000/Environment.ProcessorCount; 

PParallel.For(0, iterationsPerCore...
It shares 1250 iterations between the 8 cores

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) threading guide.
Goes from very basic threads to parallel programming in a very understandable way.
It's 5 chapters from the book c# 4.0 in a nutshell.
Personally it helped me a lot to understand threading better.